# Using is_granted in custom Symfony ExceptionController

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404

I am working on creating a custom ExceptionController in a Symfony 2 project. I would like to present different information regarding whether the user is logged in or not.

The [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#avoiding-exceptions-when-using-security-functions-in-error-templates) say, that it is not possible to use `is_granted(...)` within the ExceptionControllers template:

> The cause of this problem is that routing is done before security. If a 404 error occurs, the security layer isn't loaded and thus, the `is_granted()` function is undefined. The solution is to add the following check before using this function:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted('...') %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

This description is quite confusing to me. Should this be a solution even for 404 error? On 404 errors no security is done before presenting the error. So there is never any information of whether the user was logged in or not. How should using `app.user` change this?

I think this is only a solution for other errors like 500, etc. where security information is available. However I would like to check if I am getting it wrong here:

Can user information be used on 404 pages?

Comment: During the normal cycle, routes are matched, security voters are called then the user object is  stored in the application. Remember, even non logged in users have a user object. If this object is not present in the application, it implies security voters are not available. So, no, user info cannot be used on 404 pages.